# Problem with AlertDialog Button in android

Tags: android, button, alert

I have an Alert Dialog that is supposed to set a boolean to true. For `setPositiveButton` I have the Dialog `onclick` interface as null. When I add an `onClickListener` to the `setNegativeButtons` `onclick` interface it gives me a compile error saying: The method `setNegativeButton(int, DialogInterface.OnClickListener)` in the type `AlertDialog.Builder` is not applicable for the arguments `(String, new View.OnClickListener(){})`

Here is my code, why am I getting a compile error and how do I fix this? Thanks

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(ImTracking.this)
    .setMessage(
            Html.fromHtml(getText("http://www.cellphonesolutions.net/im-following-"
                    + getResources().getString(
                            R.string.Country))))
    .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
    // The red squigly is under the .setNegativeButton
    .setNegativeButton("Don't Remind", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences("Settings",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("ImTrackingDontRemind",true);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }).show();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is was it should be

```
  alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Don't Remind", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences("Settings",0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("ImTrackingDontRemind",true);
                        editor.commit();

    } });
```

Comment: yeap this is it, Dialog boxes are so annoying. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is your solution, you did a silly mistake there buddy.

It should not be

```
.setNegativeButton("Don't Remind", new OnClickListener()
```

It should be

```
.setNegativeButton("Don't Remind", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to providing the answer, perhaps it would also be prudent to provide an explanation of why that's the answer. Plus, Sean's question was,

> ...**why am I getting a compile error** and how do I fix this?

emphasis mine. While the accepted answer answers the latter question, it does not attempt to answer the former question.

Sean, the `onClickListner` anonymous inner class you're creating is actually a member function of `View` since you provided no class name. Your compile error stems from the fact that `AlertDialog` extends the `Dialog` class, not the `View` class and thus has an `onClickListner` member function with a different function signature:

`public abstract void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which)`

than that of `View`'s `onClickListner` member function:

`public abstract void onClick (View v)`.